# Facebook API fails and Graph works. Why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook app that works fine when I call `$facebook->api('/me')`, it returns all the user information, but it fails when I call `$facebook->api('/100006737731259')`. The error I get is:

```
array("error" => array("message" => "Unsupported get request.", "type" => "GraphMethodException", "code" => 100))
```

And the strange thing is that if I open my browser and go to `http://graph.facebook.com/100006737731259` it returns all the information with no problem (it is one test user for my app).

Have you ever had a problem like it? I do not know what can I be doing wrong.

Thank you very much

Comment: I use Facebook php SDK v3.2.2

Comment: By the way, very, very often it works properly. It is a very strange thing.

Comment: If the problem is solved, please answer your own question and mark that accepted just for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When call this API for test user, you can put empty access token OR just don't put access_token parameter at all, then you can solve it.

If you really want to put the access_token, there's the rule you have to follow:

**Prohibited access_token:**

1. Normal user's access token
2. Other app's test user access token
3. Other app access token

**Allowed access_token:**

1. Test user's access token(**Either the test user is current app's other test user or this test user 100006737731259, both is allowed!**) retrieved from https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=TEST_USER_NAME&locale=en_US&permissions=read_stream&method=post&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN (Replace the relevant APP_ID, TEST_USER_NAME, and APP_ACCESS_TOKEN)
2. Current App Access token

   *APP_ACCESS_TOKEN can be retrieved from https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials (Replace the relevant APP_SECRET)

   **App Secret can be get from https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/APP_ID/settings/ (Replace relevant APP_ID)

The proof is, if you request with other user access token, https://graph.facebook.com/100006737731259?access_token=PROHIBITED_ACCESS_TOKEN at web browser, you would get error eventually.

But if you do https://graph.facebook.com/100006737731259?access_token=Allowed_ACCESS_TOKEN OR https://graph.facebook.com/100006737731259?access_token= (left the access_token value empty) with your web browser, then you can get the data.

Comment: You are right. Anyway I think Facebook SDK should work fine with test users, because it has no sense that we have to call the API with no access token for test users and with an allowed access token for production.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that only occurs with test users. I don't know why, but it is. If you use a real user, this will not happen.